# In Javascript a child node is effected because of its parent node

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a image slider by learning from youtube. Everything was going good but i had a curiosity about a problem. You know, in slider, there are two buttons (Previous Button and Next Button). I wrote a code that

`container.animate([{opacity:'0.1'}, {opacity:'1'}], {duration: 1000, fill:'forwards'});`

This code is nice, good, beautiful but it also affects the buttons. I don't want this happens.

I tried to add `buttons.animate([{opacity:'1'},{opacity:'1'}],{duration:1, fill:'forwards'});` in functions.

```
<div class="images">
    <button id="previous" type="button">Prev</button>
    <button id="next" type="button">Next</button>
</div>


const prevButton = document.querySelector('#previous');
const nextButton = document.querySelector('#next');
const container = document.querySelector('.images');
const buttons = prevButton && nextButton;

let counter = 0;

prevButton.addEventListener('click', prev);
nextButton.addEventListener('click', next);

function next(){
    container.animate([{opacity:'0.1'}, {opacity:'1'}], {duration: 1000, fill:'forwards'});
    counter++;
    while(counter > 4){
    counter = 0;
    }
    container.style.background = `url(images/image${counter}.jpg)center/cover no-repeat`;
}

function prev(){
    container.animate([{opacity:'0.1'}, {opacity:'1'}], {duration: 1000, fill:'forwards'});
    counter--
    while(counter < 0){
        counter = 4;
    }
    container.style.background = `url(images/image${counter}.jpg)center/cover no-repeat`;

}
```

Comment: if you add a style to the parent, it will affect the child unless the child has that same element attached with a different style

Comment: Is it really necessary to have the buttons within the `.images` container? They should be outside as that container should be used only to hold the images and your code will work fine.

Comment: @gugateider I did that you said and i successed in no time at now (I am much beginner). But is there a way in javascript that blocks this, can we seperate parent and child element? I just wonder.

Comment: did you try to position your buttons in absolute?

Comment: @Luca Spezzano yes i did so. When i seperated div and button elements in html it worked.

Answer (score 1):

As @gugateider said, if you don't want the buttons to be affected by the animation on the .images, I would move them outside of that container like so:

```
<div class="slider">
    <button id="previous" type="button">Prev</button>
    <button id="next" type="button">Next</button>
    <div class="images">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can animate the .images without affecting anything with the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Opacity will affect every descendant element. From [MDN Opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity):

> `opacity` applies to the element as a whole, including its contents, even though the value is not inherited by child elements. Thus, the element and its children all have the same opacity relative to the element's background, even if they have different opacities relative to one another.

Since `opacity` is not inherited, applying `opacity: 1` to a child will not do anything as you will not be resetting an inherited value.

I like to think of what is happening as a bit of a filter.

I would suggest moving the previous and next elements outside of the container for individual slides. Many sliders will have a structure similar to this:

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slides">
    <img class="slide">
    <img class="slide">
    <!-- Instead of a IMG tag, this could be a DIV to hold text/etc. -->
  </div>
  <div class="slider-controls">
    <button class="slider-control prev">Prev</button>
    <button class="slider-control next">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```